# iOS app beta crashes on startup

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

The latest SE iOS app beta I just received instantly crashes when I open the app.

It says I do have two notifications sitting in there, so I clicked but with an instant crash as result.

Can this be fixed please?

---

- App Version: 1.6.0.5
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.0.1 (Build 14A403)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.0.6, building now.

To fix ["Peer Review" badge description is HTML-encoded in the iOS app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328567/peer-review-badge-description-is-html-encoded-in-the-ios-app), I converted badge descriptions from an `NSString` to a `SEAPIHTMLString` and updated the feed to extract the text content.  Unfortunately, the cached feed still had serialized `NSString` badges, so the data types were mismatched and the app crashed on the unrecognized selector `-[__NSCFString stringWithTextContent]:`

Comment: Fixed indeed. Thanks a lot